# RxJava2 in CursorLoader’s onLoadFinished callback

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, rx-android, android-cursorloader

To get data from database I use `CursorLoader` in the app. Once `onLoadFinished()` callback method calls the logic of app converts `Cursor` object to `List` of objects within business model requirements. That conversion (heavy operation) takes some time if there is a lot of data. That slows UI thread. I tried to start conversion in non-UI `Thread` using `RxJava2` passing `Cursor` object, but got `Exception`:

```
Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
```

Here is the part of `Fragment`'s code:

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        QueryBuilder builder;
        switch (id) {
            case Constants.FIELDS_QUERY_TOKEN:
                builder = QueryBuilderFacade.getFieldsQB(activity);
                return new QueryCursorLoader(activity, builder);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            getFieldsObservable(cursor)
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(this::showFields);
        } else {
            showNoData();
        }
    }

private static Observable<List<Field>> getFieldsObservable(Cursor cursor) {
            return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(getFields(cursor))); <-- Exception raised at this line

        }

private static List<Field> getFields(Cursor cursor) {
            List<Field> farmList = CursorUtil.cursorToList(cursor, Field.class);
            CursorUtil.closeSafely(cursor);
            return farmList;
        }
```

The purpose of using `CursorLoader` here is to get notifications from DB if there is data store updated.

**Update**
As Tin Tran suggested, I removed `CursorUtil.closeSafely(cursor);` and now I get another exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: /data/user/0/com.my.project/databases/db_file
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                          at android.database.CursorWindow.getNumRows(CursorWindow.java:225)
                                                          at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.onMove(SQLiteCursor.java:121)
                                                          at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:236)
                                                          at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:274)
                                                          at android.database.CursorWrapper.moveToNext(CursorWrapper.java:202)
                                                          at com.db.util.CursorUtil.cursorToList(CursorUtil.java:44)
                                                          at com.my.project.MyFragment.getFields(MyFragment.java:230)
```

**`cursorToList()` method of `CursorUtil`**

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> cursorToList(Cursor cursor, Class<T> modelClass) {
        ArrayList<T> items = new ArrayList<T>();
        if (!isCursorEmpty(cursor)) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) { <-- at this line (44) of the method raised that issue
                final T model = buildModel(modelClass, cursor);
                items.add(model);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I would strongly recommend having a look at [sqlbrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite).

Comment: @Lukasz, yes, I know about sqlbrite and it would be a good solution for that, but I can't add it to the project as it already big and used another orm.

Comment: May this list be updated whilst the previous data is being processed?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390030/rxjava2-in-cursorloader-s-onloadfinished-callback#comment75901123_44390030) to your question, I was interested whether the data is being updated while `getFieldsObservable()` hasn't been yet returned. I received the info I was interested [in your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390030/rxjava2-in-cursorloader-s-onloadfinished-callback#comment75903905_44452356).

As I can judge, here's what happens in your case:

- [`onLoadFinished()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D)) is called with Cursor-1
- RxJava's method is being executed on another thread with Cursor-1 (hasn't yet been finished, here Cursor-1 is being used)
- [`onLoadFinished()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D)) is called with Cursor-2, LoaderManager API takes care of closing `Cursor-1`, which is still being queried by RxJava on another thread

Thus, an exception results.

So, you'd better stick with creating your custom [`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) (which [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) extends from). This [`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html) will incorporate all the logics that [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) has (basically one-to-one copy), but would return already sorted/filter object in `onLoadFinished(YourCustomObject)`. Thus, the operation, that you wished to perform using RxJava would actually be done by your loader in it's [`loadInBackground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html#loadInBackground()) method.

Here's the snapshot of the changes that `MyCustomLoader` will have in `loadInBackground()` method:

```
public class MyCustomLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<PojoWrapper> {
  ...
  /* Runs on a worker thread */
  @Override
  public PojoWrapper loadInBackground() {
    ...
    try {
      Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(mUri, mProjection, mSelection,
          mSelectionArgs, mSortOrder, mCancellationSignal);
      ...

      // `CursorLoader` performs following:
      // return cursor;

      // We perform some operation here with `cursor`
      // and return PojoWrapper, that consists of `cursor` and `List<Pojo>`
      List<Pojo> list = CursorUtil.cursorToList(cursor, Field.class);
      return new PojoWrapper(cursor, list);
    } finally {
      ...
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

Where `PojoWrapper` is:

```
public class PojoWrapper {
  Cursor cursor;
  List<Pojo> list;

  public PojoWrapper(Cursor cursor, List<Pojo> list) {
    this.cursor = cursor;
    this.list = list;
  }
}
```

Thus, in [`onLoadFinished()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html#onLoadFinished(android.content.Loader%3CD%3E,%20D)) you do not have to take care of delegating the job to another thread, because you already have done it in your [`Loader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) implementation:

```
@Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<PojoWrapper> loader, PojoWrapper data) {
      List<Pojo> alreadySortedList = data.list;
}
```

[Here's](https://pastebin.com/wQ7c2u86) the entire code of `MyCustomLoader`.

Answer (score 4):

> The loader will release the data once it knows the application is no longer using it. For example, if the data is a cursor from a CursorLoader, you should not call close() on it yourself.
>   From: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

You should not close the cursor yourself which I think `CursorUtil.closeSafely(cursor)` does.

You can use `switchMap` operator to implement that. It does exactly what we want

```
private PublishSubject<Cursor> cursorSubject = PublishSubject.create()

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    cursorSubject
        .switchMap(new Func1<Cursor, Observable<List<Field>>>() {
             @Override public Observable<List<Field>> call(Cursor cursor) {
                  return getFieldsObservable(cursor);
             }
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(this::showFields);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursorSubject.onNext(cursor)
}
```

You now need to modify `showFields` to and `getFieldsObservable` to account for empty `Cursor`

Comment: Yes, it does close the `Cursor`. But OP closes it when he no longer needs it, meaning that he has already *"parsed"* `farmList` from the `Cursor` and he no longer needs to leave that `Cursor` opened. I see no problems here.

Comment: Yes, but after he closes the `Cursor`, the `CursorLoader` may still need to access the cursor. If it does, then an `Exception`is thrown

Comment: I see what you mean. I wonder whether `LoaderManager` is not smart enough to perform `if` check and load another time when `Cursor` is closed.

Comment: I've tested without closing the cursor as Tin Tran suggested and got another exception, added trace as update to the question.

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace ?

Comment: @TinTran, it raised at this line `List<Field> farmList = CursorUtil.cursorToList(cursor, Field.class);` of getFields(). Trace is in updated.

Comment: The problem is `Cursor` is not thread-safe. While you are converting the cursor to `List<Field>`, a new `Cursor` arrive in `onLoadFinished` and the old Cursor is close. Therefore, the io thread accessing it will throw the exception.

Comment: looks like you are right, I see that `onLoadFinished` calls three times during 2 seconds as new objects of `Cursor` arrived. But, what do you suggest here is it possible somehow to move out `cursorToList` method from UI thread, maybe make `cursor` thread-safe or start `CursorLoader` from `io` thread from the beginning or maybe another solution?

Comment: What are u doing with the List<Field> after parsing?. Is it large ?

Comment: @TinTran, "`Cursor` is not thread-safe" I also was inclined that way, but as you can see in `CursorLoader#loadInBackground`, it calls `getContext().getContentResolver().query()`, which in turn creates the `Cursor` while being in background thread. Later, this `Cursor` would be dispatched to the UI thread, and we can safely use it. So, what's your clarification concerning `Cursor`'s non-threadsafety?

Comment: @azizbekian I mean the usage of Cursor is not thread safe. You can close a `Cursor` while other thread is reading/accessing it.

Comment: Oh, I see what you meant. As far as I know, that has nothing to do with threadsafety. Normally, thread-safe means, that if some change is being done to the object on one thread, that change is visible for the second thread. Thus, `Cursor` seems to be thread-safe.

Comment: @TinTran, `getFieldsObservable(cursor)` is a heavy operation, lets assume it takes 10 seconds. Now, while performing this job, another update comes from `Loader`, which closes the previous cursor, thus the heavy operation crashes. I cannot see how this actually will solve the problem, but yes, it is much more concise!

Comment: We can modify the `getFieldsObservable` to check for `subscriber.isUnsubscribe()` before every accessing operation on the cursor. I think the Loader won't close the Cursor before making the new Cursor with the new result and deliver to us. If we have the new Cursor, the previous `Observable` on the old Cursor is unsubscribed. We can access the `Subscriber` using the `Observable.create()` to create `Observable`.

Comment: `to check for subscriber.isUnsubscribe() before every accessing operation on the cursor` - the problem is following: you are interacting with cursor on main thread, whereas `CursorLoader` creates another cursor on a background thread, so there is no synchronization between these two threads, you cannot tell "hey, CursorLoader, do not close this cursor for a while until I finish interacting with it".